# Is it okay to use Loctite instead of pinning an outer tie rod lock nut?

Tags: steering, safety, rack-and-pinion

I'm doing a rack and pinion rebuild. My rack uses lock nuts to secure the inner rod to the rack bar. The inner rods are manually preloaded with the adjustment nut and locked into place with a lock nut. Normally, the adjustment/lock nuts are pinned into place. I'm curious if the inner tie rod lock nuts can be secured with Loctite instead of pinning?

I assume that blue Loctite would not be strong enough, so I guess red would need to be used. Or maybe some form of green should be used?

If I did this, I would use red Loctite and mark the lock nut position with a paint pen so I could see if it slips at all. Does this seem reasonable and safe?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the pins.  Ask yourself, why did the manufacturer design this with pins instead of thread locker when the locker is almost certainly less expensive to purchase and assemble?

Comment: Was thread locker common in the late 70s/early 80s?

Comment: @WrenT.  I'm not clear how that matters.  Pins (i.e. cotter pins) are still commonly used on cars and trucks in 2023.  Also, that wasn't your question.

Comment: @WrenT. -  Completely agree with jwh20 here. Why are you even considering entrusting your life and the life of others with Locktite? Especially when pinning is tried and true as well as industry standard.

Comment: I was just curious about it. Given the advice here, I'm clearly going to pin the parts. I was just curious if thread locker was commonly used when the car was designed.